# How to create a filter expression from selection QGIS 3.6.3

Tags: qgis, filter

I need to create a filter expression to filter only the selected polygons in a layer. Yes I know I can save the selected elements to a new layer but this solution is not suitable for me.

I managed to create a virtual field with is_selected() that return true only on selected elements, but I cannot use this virtual field in filter composer window.

I really need a "filter from selection" workaround!

Comment: Duplicate of: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169957/copy-convert-selection-into-filter-query-builder-of-qgis  ?

Comment: Sorry but having a python script that return a string to paste in the filter dialog box is not a good solution for me (Also you have to adapt the string to suite your fields names..)

Comment: duplicate of: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/336017/creating-a-virtual-layer-based-on-a-virtual-field-for-dynamic-selection-in-qgis/336041#336041,